# Как сделать так, чтобы при становлении элемента невидимым другие не вставали на его место?

Tags: html, jquery

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">

      <tr>

        <td width="85%" valign="top">
        <div class = "content">
          <ul class = "books">

          <li>
            <img src = "img.jpg" width="150" height="200" >

            <p>
              Текст
            </p></li>

          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </td>


    <td  width="15%" valign="top" id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href>Ссылка1</a></li>
        <li><a href>Ссылка2</a></li>
        <li><a href>Ссылка3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Слева - текст с картнками, справа - меню.
Проблема в том, что когда элемент #menu становится невидимым, текст растягивается и занимает место меню. А нужно, чтобы текст за пределы своего столба в таблице (который занимает 85%) не высовывался. Как это устроить? 
Вот jquery

```
var hght = 95;   
    var mrg = 0; 

    $(function(){

      var elem = $('#menu');
      var top = $(this).scrollTop();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
          top = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (top+mrg < hght) {
          elem.css('top', (hght-top));
        } else {
          if (top+mrg > 200){
          elem.fadeOut();
          }
        }

    });

});
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае надо оперировать не ячейкой таблицы, а некоторым контейнером внутри этой таблицы.

Самое простое решение - прятать не ячейку, а `ul` внутри этой ячейки.

Так же некоторые вопросы вызывает работа с ячейками таблицы как с блочными элементами. Явно есть некоторое недопонимание идеалогии верстки.

Answer (score 1):

Я могу ошибаться, но в CSS сейчас есть [Visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) Он как раз подходит под ваше описание задачи. Скрывает элемент, но занимаемое место в странице не схлопывается.

```js
$('button#btn').on('click', function() {
  var visibility = $('#menu').css('visibility');
  $('#menu').css("visibility", (visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
</div>
<button id="btn">Chenge Visible</button>
```